# dash searchable dropdown foreground/background input color

Tags: python, css, plotly, dropdown, plotly-dash

I am trying to modify the foreground or background color used by a *dash* searchable *Dropdown* when a text is input to search in the list.

The input text is black which is almost impossible to read using a dark theme.

Through the *css* I am able to modify a lot of colors, example :

- the color of the text in the list is red doing :

  `.Select-control, .Select, .Select-value-label, .Select-clear-zone { color: red; }` or `.Select-menu-outer {color: red; }`
- the color of the background for the current value or *Select ...* if no value is blue doing :

  `.Select--single > .Select-control .Select-value, .Select-placeholder { background-color: blue; }`
- the color of the text for the already current value or *Select ...* if no value is green doing :

  `.Select.has-value.Select--single > .Select-control .Select-value .Select-value-label, .Select.has-value.is-pseudo-focused.Select--single > .Select-control .Select-value .Select-value-label { color: green; }`
- it it even possible to change the color of the text in the list to be purple when the mouse is inside the list area doing `.Select-menu-outer div:hover { color: purple; }`

But I cannot found a way to change the color of the input text or its background to search.

How to do through the *css* or using options (*style*) in the Python code defining the *dash_core_components Dropdown*?

Note there is a similar question asked in May 2020 in [Plotly forum](https://community.plotly.com/t/cannot-change-style-of-searchable-dropdown-input-color/39639) but unfortunately still without answer

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can target the font color via,

```
input{
   color: red;
}
```

and the backgrounp color of the open drop down via,

```
.is-open>.Select-control {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, for the input color how to limit it to the dropdown input ?

Comment: For the background that does not work, that has no effect